# access nested uncounted arrays in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have nested arrays those the user made.
I want a JavaScript code to access for example "g" element in it

```js
var nestedArrays = [
  [a,b,c,d],
  [e,f,[
    g,h
  ]]
];
```

in this example i can access "g" element using this code

```js
var element = nestedarrays[2][1][1];
```

**BUT** if "g" is nested in 100 of arrays i have to write a lot of square brackets as it

```js
var g = nestedArrays[2][3][1][?][?].....[?];
```

***OR*** i don't know how much "g" is nested

***IS*** there an easy code to get any element in the nested arrays  with pure javascript or jquery ???

Comment: Sure, depending on what "g" is, and how you decide to define "equality". It's a recursive find operation.

Comment: Recursion. This should give you all the information you need: [How can I access and process nested objects, arrays or JSON?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11922383/how-can-i-access-and-process-nested-objects-arrays-or-json) (whether that's "easy" or not is for you to decide).

Answer (score 0):

###### We all know that array are zero-based.

In your first Example to access `'g'` You need to access:

- the second position (index `[1]`) which is `['e','f',['g','h']]`
- then access the third position (index `[2]`) which is `['g','h']`
- finally the first position (index `[0]`) and you get `'g'`.

```js
var nestedArrays = [['a','b','c','d'],['e','f',['g','h']]];
let x = nestedArrays[1][2][0];
console.log(x); // g
```

So from that we can say that to access `'g'` 
We need to follow this road of indices `[1,2,0]`

```js
var nestedArrays = [['a','b','c','d'],['e','f',['g','h']]];
let roadToG = [1,2,0];

for(let i = 0; i < roadToG.length; i++){
    nestedArrays = nestedArrays[roadToG[i]];
}
console.log(nestedArrays); // g
```

> BUT if "g" is nested in 100 of arrays i have to write a lot of square brackets as it `var g = nestedArrays[2][3][1][?][?].....[?];`

In case we want to access `'g'` dynamically without hard code *the road of indices*; We must loop recursively in array till we find `'g'`, in looping we keep track of road

```js
function loopRecursively( arr, x ,roadToX = []){
    if(JSON.stringify(arr).indexOf(x) == -1) return null; //in edge case where there is no x in array; we just return null!
    for ( let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++ ) {
        if( arr[i] == x ){
            roadToX.push(i);
        } else if( Array.isArray( arr[i] ) && JSON.stringify(arr[i]).indexOf(x) != -1 ){
            roadToX.push(i);
            loopRecursively( arr[i] , x, roadToX);
        }
    }
    return roadToX;
}
let nestedArrays = [['a','b','c','d'],['e','f',['g','h']]];
console.log( loopRecursively( nestedArrays, 'g' ) ); // [1, 2, 0]
```

Comment: I want an element that's deep in the nestedarray
I tried the second code you have written in console and it worked but in my code it displays this error >>

Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input

Answer (score 0):

If you're just trying to find a particular element you could [flatten](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat) the array and [find](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) it that way.

```js
var nestedArrays = [
  ['a','b','c','d'],
  ['e','f',[
    'g','h'
  ]]
];

const g = nestedArrays.flat(Infinity).find(x => x === 'g');

console.log(g);
```

Comment: i didn't mean that but it will help in another part of code.... thanks